# Parse Javascript. Trying to use the data I pulled from a query

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I am trying to create a link to another page so you can view one recipe individually after the query search. Having trouble finding how to do this after the query finds all the results. I want it so when you click on the title of the recipe, it directs you to another page and presents it with that specific data of that recipe.

```
Parse.initialize("ID","JSID");

     var Recipes = Parse.Object.extend("Recipes");
var recipesQuery = new Parse.Query(Recipes);
recipesQuery.exists("Images");
recipesQuery.equalTo("feeds", "4");

recipesQuery.find({
    success: function(results) {
        //Return values of feeding 4 onto the page
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            var object = results[i];
            (function($) { 
            $('#results-table').append(object.get('objectId') +'<tr><td><b>' + '<img src="' + object.get('Images').url() + '"width="330px">' + '</td><td>' + '<b><p>' + '<a href="recipesContent2.html?' + object.id + '" rel="external">' + object.get('recTitle') + '</a>' + '</b></p>' + '<img src="images/clock.png">' + object.get('Time') + '</td></tr>');
            })(jQuery);




        }
    },

    error: function(error) {
        alert("Error");
    }
});
```

so here is my code now for recipesContent2.html page

```
    Parse.initialize("id","jsid");
     var objectId = window.location.pathname.split('?').slice(-1);

  var Recipes = Parse.Object.extend("Recipes");
  var recipeQuery = new Parse.Query(Recipes);
  recipeQuery.exists("Images");
  recipeQuery.equalTo("objectId", objectId);

  recipeQuery.find({
    success: function(results) {
        for (var i in results) {
        var object = results[i];
            (function($) { 
            $('#results-tab').append(object.get('objectId') +'<tr><td><b>' + '<img src="' + object.get('Images').url() + '"width="330px">' + '</td><td>' + '<b><p>'  + object.get('recTitle') + '</b></p>' + '<img src="images/clock.png">' + object.get('Time') + '</td></tr>');
            })(jQuery);
        }
    },

    error: function( error) {
        alert("Error:" + error.code+ " " + error.message);
    }
});
</script>
```

and now I'm getting this error "Error:102 equality needs a value instead of [recipesContent.html]

Comment: This is 50% of a question.  The other 50% is what's not working and what have you tried.

Comment: This question is getting views and answers offered.  Please, instead of posting a duplicate with additional info, press edit here and add the additional info here.  The other question adds the error being received.  How about logging results of the string manipulation to see if valid-looking stuff is being generated?  That's the 2nd half of the question.  (And asking another dup question is unfair to @Bluety who is trying to help on this one).

Comment: Sorry, been edited now. Been working on this problem for 3 days and I feel very close to solving it so was in a rush to fix it. I do apologise

Answer (score 0):

You can create link like so (in your append content):

```
.append('<a href="http://mywebsite.com/recipe/' + object.id + '"><img></a>')
```

On the target page, you can get objectId from the url and make query like so:

```
var objectId = window.location.pathname.split('/').slice(-1);

var Recipes = Parse.Object.extend("Recipes");
var recipeQuery = new Parse.Query(Recipes);
    recipeQuery.get(objectId, {
        success: function(recipe) {
            console.log(recipe);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log('Error');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for responding! So i put this into my code and received an error. Said my query.find function was anonymous.

Comment: I have update my code. Can you copy past your error ?

Comment: parse-1.3.4.min.js:1 POST https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Recipes 400 (Bad Request)
recSingleUpload2.js:13 Error

Comment: Can you add your recSingleUpload2.js file ? You can have more details of your error in network tab (press F12 key). In network tab you can click on your bad request and get more informations.

Comment: I put in this code on my target page and recieve this GET file://filespace/Home/msmith26/PP%205/recipesContent2.html/QVHWumCj4I net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND.    The objectId of the variable is coming after the .html/ but no page is found

Comment: Have you create this page recipesContent2.html ? It's an other problem

Comment: Here is the code inside recipesContent2.html. Right now I replaced the / with ? and uploads the page, but still comes up with console.log error

Comment: var objectId = window.location.pathname.split('?').slice(-1);

var Recipes = Parse.Object.extend("Recipes");
var recipeQuery = new Parse.Query(Recipes);
   recipeQuery.get("objectId", {
        success: function(recipe) {
            console.log(recipe);
        },
        error: function(results, error) {
            console.log('Error');
        }
    });

Comment: If you replace '/' by '?' you must change  
`var objectId = window.location.pathname.split('/').slice(-1);`  
by  
`var objectId = window.location.search.split('?').slice(-1);`

Comment: Yeah i've done that. But i am still console.log error

Comment: now I'm getting this error "Error:102 equality needs a value instead of [recipesContent.html]